# JavaScript - XHR - Add SSL Certificate Details to a Request

Tags: javascript, request, xmlhttprequest

I've got a POST request I'm trying to make, which I've already made in PHP.

For some reasons I've had with PHP, I'm trying to make it in JavaScript again.
I've got jQuery and I'm using generated XHR code from a captured request by Postman (a software that catches requests).

I'm running into some issues in having the request accepted, because the website has SSL. I was able to add the SSL certificate details with cURL in PHP.
I've searched online and I didn't find a way to add it in XHR in JavaScript.

Is it possible to do so? If so, how?
I've got the SSL certificate itself downloaded (got it using Firefox).
In cURL I needed to load some things from the certificate file. 
Do I need to do the same with XHR?

Also, I've never worked with XHR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you install a certificate for XHR to use depends on which implementation of XHR you are using. From a web browser, it just uses the web browser's certificate library (and most browsers just use the OS' library).

Keep in mind that standard [cross origin limitations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) will apply.